# WSO2is configuring Identity Provider for SSOCircle

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server

I've been trying to configure WSO2is to accept a SAML auth request from Spring Security and pass it along to an external IDP for authentication.  I've configured the SP and IDP on WSO2 correctly enough to have my request be redirected to SSOCircle, but when Circle sends the SAML response back to WSO2 it gives a "Not a valid SAML 2.0 Request Message!" error page. Which this makes sense as it's not a request being sent to the server.

I think my problem revolves around the AssertionConsumerService in the metadata I've uploaded to Circle "https://MyLocalHost:8080/samlsso" which is the url for the Resident Identity Provider. I've been hunting around different end point to use for, but have not been find anything.

The closest I've been able to get was following the example here https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Single+Sign-On+with+SAML+2.0 but this appears to be used for just logging into the WSO2 server itself.

EDIT after changing the endpoint to commonauth

Here are the logs after the request lands on the server.

```
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler} -  SAMLSSOAuthenticator returned: INCOMPLETE {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler}
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler} -  SAMLSSOAuthenticator is redirecting {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.step.impl.DefaultStepHandler}
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler} -  Step is not complete yet. Redirecting to outside. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.sequence.impl.DefaultStepBasedSequenceHandler}
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Session data key is null in the request {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator}
```

Comment: I believe I've found the correct endpoint now. Found this blog post about Federated Auths http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/04/30/integrating-salesforce-with-wso2-identity-server-as-saml2-sso-idp/ Now I'm seeing this error, `[2015-11-11 10:34:34,368] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache` With no warnings about signatures being invalid.

Comment: The AssortionConsumerService URL would be https://MyLocalHost:8080/commonauth. Are you using a clustered WSO2 server? Does it still happen after server restart? Please set the logs to debug and post the output. Have you tried IDP initiated SSO?

Comment: I've added the debug logs after Circle responses. The only thing that stands out that there is a debug log about a session key being null, but I can't find anything online that would point to that being the problem.